# Ubuntu restarted on its' own, hasn't been able to connect to internet since last week

Tags: networking, internet, wired

I have a dual boot on my desktop and am using the Windows side at the moment. Last Tuesday night I (thought) I shut down my computer, but discovered in the morning that it was on and waiting for me to log in. When I did, I couldn't access the Internet. Other devices in the house were fine, and when I re-booted to Windows, I found it would also connect. So it wasn't the service, the router, the cable, etc.

I have 20.04.2 64 bit on a HP Compaq - 6005 - Pro - SFF - PC. I avoid using the terminal, but if instructions are specific (copy/paste-able), I can manage.

Comment: @user535733 duly noted and corrected.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: @waltinator According to the logs, it looks like numerous attempts to connect, but ultimately the "association took too long." There were a lot of lines of text which I would translate "gonna try this." "Nope." "now trying this." "Nope." and repeat, until it gets to the line about "took too long." Is this helpful without the exact phrasing?

Comment: No. A user's "interpretation" of an error message is never helpful. Users are inaccurate, omit details, and offer interpretation without understanding. Edit [Edit] your question to add information. If your log is too big, use one of the free storage sites (pastebin, dropbox, ...).

Comment: is "fast startup" disabled on the Windows side?

Comment: @Nmath I tried to find  "fast startup" in "Settings" on the Windows side and couldn't tell if I was looking at the right thing. I normally just use Ubuntu, and assume that I can't access Windows and that it isn't running in the background, so maybe I'm wrong about what "dual boot" means. But if I have to dig around in the HP start-up pages, I need to know where to look on what screen.